# Is there a reason Herbert used the name "Jesus Lewis"?

Tags: frank-herbert, the-jesus-incident

In the (lesser known, non-Dune) novel *The Jesus Incident* one of the character's name's is "Jesus Lewis".

We learn in an important scene that it's normally pronounced in the Spanish style (i.e. "Haysoos") when Ship pronounces it in the English style (i.e. "Geezus") and this surprises a character.

Frank Herbert is well known for playing word games with character names in all of his works.   ("Irulan" and "Noah Arkwright" are two of my favorite examples.)

Did he give any explanation for using the name "Jesus Lewis" other than the connection to the biblical Jesus (and a connection at the end of the book which I won't give away)?

Comment: Random thought:  [Jeez Louise!](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/jeez-louise)

Comment: Frank Herbert's non-dune novels and short stories were rockin', mostly dealing with immortality and class warfare.  Also the creation of and the effects of gods created by science.

Comment: Jesus is not an uncommon name in South America.

Comment: @Izkata - WOW! That actually may be the answer!  :D  It kind of fits in a depraved sort of way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like [Izkata's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28022/is-there-a-reason-herbert-used-the-name-jesus-lewis/223563#comment54597_28022) so much I'm going to repost it as a real answer.

It seems to be word play on [Jeez Louise](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/jeez-louise). I believe this is just the kind of weird name logic that Herbert would have used, considering the character.

Comment: Keep the credit - I know nothing of the author or the book, I just made the comment because it sounded funny

Answer (score 1):

The entire "Jesus Lewis" character is the most perplexing thing about the novel to me.  The choice of name sticks out like a sore thumb considering how prominently the biblical Jesus is discussed over the course of the novel.

But anyway, while I'm not sure exactly what point Frank Herbert was trying to make, I'm pretty sure the choice of name is a reference to [Lewis's Trilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis%27s_trilemma).

What is revealed about "Jesus Lewis" at the end of the novel more or less confirms it for me.

Edit: Sorry for the incomplete response, as you suspected I was trying to avoid spoilers.  I've added more info hidden behind the spoiler tag.

> In summary, Lewis's Trilemma is the argument that Jesus must have been either been 1) an evil person who lied about what he preached 2) a crazy person who was deluded about what he preached 3) a true agent of God.  The point of the argument is to reject compromises.  It's not enough to merely hold Jesus as an example of moral humanity.  Either you accept him completely as divine and worship him or you must reject him as a false prophet.

-

> Concerning Jesus Lewis specifically, whatever pretense the novel had for presenting his name as a coincidence (Heysoos vs Geezus) was dispelled in the conclusion when Ship explicitly identifies Jesus Lewis as Its agent and whisks him away in a flash of light.  It specifically refers to him as "a real Devil" and "the other half of me", implied to be the only character that was not an independent agent and directly following Ship's designs.

-

> Following this, Hali Ekel (who was chosen to witness the crucixion of "Yaisuah" (Jesus Christ) in a time travel event) asks Ship if Yaisuah was also "another filament from one of Your dreams?"  Ship's answer is that it does not matter if Yaisuah was real or fictional.  The lesson was that Yaisuah was the "ultimate essence of goodness", and Jesus Lewis "its opposite", and it was necessary for the Shipmen to experience both to understand them.  Finally, Ship itself did not want to be "WorShipped" as a God, but encourage humans to achieve their own consciousness/conscience and become independent.  In other words it rejects Lewis's Trilemma.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to expand on what "confirms it for you" at the end of the novel and why it is a reference to this? I've never heard of Lewis's trilemma before and I shouldn't have to do extra research to work out what your answer is saying. If you need to you can hide the bits about the books ending with spoiler markdown, just add `>!` to the start of the paragraph you want to hide.

Comment: Presumably this is the same "connection at the end of the book" the OP alluded to?

Comment: @DavidW That can be included with the spoiler protection system we have on SE, so I'll offer that the Carrot's request is a fair one.

Comment: Welcome, Piotr.   SF&F SE uses a particular format.  If you want to avoid posting a spoiler from the end of the book, I have added a spiler text box for you to include that to address the comment that TheLethalCarrot made. Just type over the text I have in there with the info requested.  The [tour] and the [help] provide further guidance on how SE sites work best.