# What was the wordplay in the name Irulan?

Tags: dune, names, frank-herbert

> Frank Herbert is well known for playing word games with character names in all of his works. ("**Irulan**" and "Noah Arkwright" are two of my favorite examples (from [this Q](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28022/the-jesus-incident-is-there-a-reason-herbert-used-the-name-jesus-lewis?rq=1))

Noah Arkwright is kind of obvious.

**But what was the word play in "Irulan"?** (aside from her mother's name being Anirul, which I guess whasn't what OP referred to?)

Comment: I tried googling but only got Wikipedia (nothing I could find on the name) and a bunch of baby naming sites.

Comment: Baby naming sites?  People are naming their daughters after Irulan?!

Comment: @Keen - I think it's quite a nice name

Comment: [6 x Ghanima's a year](http://www.babycenter.com/babyNameAllPops.htm?babyNameId=284785) vs [17 Irulans](http://www.babycenter.com/babyNameAllPops.htm?babyNameId=100655)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Her name is an anagram of RUINAL, as Ghanima points out in Children of Dune

> “The fact that I remember the expression and you’ve never even heard
> it before should give you pause,” Ghanima said. “It was an old
> expression of scorn when you Bene Gesserit were young. But if that
> doesn’t chasten you, **ask yourself what your royal parents could’ve
> been thinking of when they named you Irulan? Or is it Ruinal?”**
>
> In spite of her training, Irulan flushed. “You’re trying to goad me, Ghanima.”
>
> “And you tried to use Voice on me. On me! I remember the first human efforts in that direction. **I remember then, Ruinous Irulan**. Now, get out of here, all of you.”

Answer (score 2):

It's an anagram of Urinal, which is probably not something you'd want to call your daughter.

Comment: That may be true, but I don't think that was what Frank Herbert was driving at :-)

Comment: @Richard That's purely speculative. How do you know Frank Herbert's intentions?

Comment: Surely this answer is just taking the piss.