# How many characters in Dune are fictionalizations of real people?

Tags: dune, frank-herbert

In the appendices to Dune, Frank Herbert refers to a book by Pander Oulson, a transparent anagram of Poul Anderson. How many other characters, major, minor, or single appearance, are fictionalizations of real people, whether tuckerized, roman à clef, or other disguise?

Comment: Loosely related (by the thread of names that are anagrams): [What was the wordplay in the name Irulan?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/84394/30482)

Comment: Krefter Brahn (an anagram of Frank Herbert) appears in one of the Dune sequels written by Herbert's son's ghostwriter.

Answer (score 11):

There is at least one other deliberate anagramatisation in the Dune novels;

> *"For a more detailed study [of Krimskell Fiber] see **Holjance
>   Vohnbrook's** 'The Strangler Vines of Ecaz' "*

Holjance Vohnbrook is an anagram of John Holbrook Vance, the real name of [Jack Vance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Vance), a contemporary of Frank Herbert on the scifi book circuit.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the character Piter DeVries has always seemed to me a reference to American author Peter DeVries.  I know of no connection between him and Herbert but it seems obvious.

Comment: This feels like a guess based on the fact that the names are similar. Now, if you could prove some sort of connection between them...